# When mysql innodb undo log write and fsync to disk?

Tags: mysql, innodb, log

Before transaction commit , every dml operation will modify innodb page which will flush to disk and generate undo log , so when the undo log write and fsync to disk to ensure rollback ?

Answer (score 2):

- Make data changes to the blocks in the buffer_pool, but do not write them to disk.
- Put changes to secondary indexes (eg for `INSERT`) into the Change Buffer for later processing.  Again, no write to disk (yet).
- Write and fsync the undo log file *if* `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1` (else this write/fsync is delayed).
- Tell the client that the `COMMIT` is finished.

The idea is to have no more than one fsync per `COMMIT`.  Otherwise, performance would be really bad.

If you are using Replication, then the binlog is written to (see `log_bin`) and possibly fsync'd (see `sync_binlog`).  And the data is shipped to each Slave.  I don't know exactly where these happen in the sequence.

If you are using Galera / FXC / Group Replication, the syncing to the other nodes adds another dimension to the question.  (I'll assume you don't need these details.)

Comment: I see . But even use `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit ` , but the unod log must flush to disk before data page flush to disk to ensuore rollback correcty , so  flush log to dish while transaction commit , it's late ; Because the dirty data page can flush to disk before transaction commit.

Answer (score 1):

That is up to your system configuration. See for example:

- [mysql innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit clarification](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/44119)
- [Is it dangerous to use transaction log flush delay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14989286)
- [`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit) in the MySQL reference manual.

Comment: I see . But even use `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit ` , but the unod log must flush to disk before data page flush to disk to ensure rollback correcty , so  flush log to dish while transaction commit , it's late ; Because the dirty data page can flush to disk before transaction commit.

Comment: And `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit ` is about redo log , not undo log .